# php automated post testing

Tags: php, post, curl

i have a page in my site as test.php .and the content of test.php is as follows :

```
<?php
$testpostvalue=$_POST["testpostvalue"];
chmod("testpost.php", 0755);
$my_file = "testpost.php";
$handle = fopen($my_file, "w") or die("Cannot open file:  ".$my_file);
fwrite($handle, $testpostvalue);
chmod("testpost.php", 0644);
?>
```

i want to run the following code from my localhost:

```
<?
$testpostvalue='
<html>
<title>test post</title>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<center>
<style>
body{background-color:#000000;color:#000000;}
</style>
<img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-2xHOAvaIImM/Ts-S6N8lSeI/AAAAAAAADDo/zBr0JfTVvSs/s320/image-708144.jpg"WIDTH="500" HEIGHT="500"</a>
<center>
<body>';


$useragent="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0b; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Alexa Toolbar; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
$url2='http://mysite.com/test.php';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"testpostvalue=".$testpostvalue);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "COOKIE.txt"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "COOKIE.txt"); 
$buffer = curl_exec($ch);
```

but when I run this code from my localhost the post is being updated.But there is some problem with the image link.The image link appears like this on the test.php :

```
<img src=/"http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-2xHOAvaIImM/Ts-S6N8lSeI/AAAAAAAADDo/zBr0JfTVvSs/s320/image-708144.jpg"WIDTH="500" HEIGHT="500"</a>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You code works file but i would not advice you to send html file like that try

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"testpostvalue=". bin2hex($testpostvalue));
```

And

```
fwrite($handle, pack("H*",$testpostvalue));
```

Comment: that might work, but isn't curl supposed to be safe? Why would you advise this? Is a honest question to learn a bit more.

Comment: Tested it and saw that since your are using `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` .. with binary characters  .. Output may not be as expected

Comment: @ BABA 
i used your first advise.but the output comes 
??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????Ð?????????

Comment: Yes .. if base64 can not send a correct out then somthing is wrong ... I observed it too that is why i changed it to hex @Force Ex

Comment: thanx,it works as expected. BABA you are great :)

Answer (score 0):

I would first try cleaning the HTML code since there are some errors, specially around the image check with this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test post</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body{background-color:#000000;color:#000000;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-2xHOAvaIImM/Ts-S6N8lSeI/AAAAAAAADDo/zBr0JfTVvSs/s320/image-708144.jpg"WIDTH="500" HEIGHT="500" />
    <center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no problem with the html part.can u give any idea so that the image link appears correctly on the output page?